# Clean tree view in Airflow interface

Tags: python, airflow

I have an externally triggered DAG that I am running hundreds of times every day. I would like to avoid having task meta data accumulate indefinitely in the DAG Tree View (see screenshot below). What's the best approach to handle this? Log in to the meta data server and delete entries for these runs?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the box, Airflow's metadata database will keep the DAG run and task instance metadata indefinitely.

You could delete the data from these tables manually, or even automate pruning it with a DAG.

You might be interested in the [teamclairvoyant/airflow-maintenance-dags](https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-maintenance-dags) repo which provides a `db-cleanup` DAG specifically for this use case:

> A maintenance workflow that you can deploy into Airflow to periodically clean out the DagRun, TaskInstance, Log, XCom, Job DB and SlaMiss entries to avoid having too much data in your Airflow MetaStore.

Also, in the Airflow web app, you can adjust the number of runs dropdown in the DAG Tree View to show a bigger/smaller window of time if you want to preserve the data in the database but just not see it in the UI at the moment.